# LostFocus event firing upon getting Focus

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an `itemscontrol` that is bound to a collection of objects.

in the data template, i bind an action that is to be used by all of the controls created if their focus is lost.

In the control, there is a textbox so if there are 1 items in the item controls ItemSource, there will be 2 textboxes.

Now, if Textbox 1 has focus and I click somewhere besides Textbox 2, the action is executed  once (because the focus was lost). But if I click in Textbox 2, the action is executed twice. Why?

```xml
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,5" ItemsSource="{Binding
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
        AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Collection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ct:CollectionItem}">
            <cc:TestControl
                ValueChangedAction="{Binding
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                    AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=ValueChangedAction}"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This is the Control.

```xml
<ewt:DecimalUpDown  Tag="{Binding Uid}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="10,5,10,5"
    FormatString="C2"  ShowButtonSpinner="False" VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Value="{Binding Value}" LostFocus="DecimalUpDown_LostFocus" />
```

The bound action is executed in this event handler.

Comment: OK, what's your action supposed to do? Is it taking action on the source of the binding in some way (e.g. is something happening to the bound window?) Assuming the answer is 'yes' to this question, see my answer below.

Comment: Does `DecimalUpDown` have the textbox in question? Because if so, then your `DecimalUpDown` may be triggering a `LostFocus` event (see your code you posted in `ewt:DecimalUpDown`, there's a `@LostFocus` attribute), as well as the textbox--which is a constituent control of the `DecimalUpDown`--that you're binding to.

Answer (score 0):

If your action is supposed to update the source of the binding (e.g. the Window, it looks like from your example), you might want to try adding `OneWayToSource` to your Binding so that binding only occurs one way—from the textbox to whatever it's bound to.

Comment: Essentially, the action is going to update the item source of the ItemsControl. That is to say, if there are 2 items, changing the value in the textbox of one is meant to update the value in the text box of the other